# Service Broker in Database/Programming

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, service-broker

**[Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

1. What can be the Benefits of Programming with Service Broker?
2. In which condition one should use Service Broker?
3. Do you have Sample link for Code/Video that easily/precisely explains it's usage?

Answer (score 1):

> Queuing and asynchronous messaging are needed for many database
>   applications today. Service Broker provides a new, queue-based durable
>   messaging framework to address these needs. Using the Transact-SQL API
>   provided by Service Broker, you can easily develop services to handle
>   application requirements for queuing or asynchronous communications.
>
> Some of the benefits of programming with Service Broker are:
>
> Flexible development: The programs used in a single distributed
>   application can be written in multiple languages. Each program
>   provides the functionality of each distributed application component.
>
> Improved security: You can express security requirements via
>   certificates, so application components do not need to share the same
>   security context. Service Broker uses SQL Server security features to
>   help you secure your applications.
>
> Transactional processing: Message processing occurs within SQL Server
>   transactions to ensure data integrity. Service Broker supports remote
>   transactional messaging over a standard connection to the database.
>
> Guaranteed ordering: Service Broker provides strong guarantees
>   regarding the delivery and processing of a related set of messages
>   exactly once and in order, so no additional coding is required to
>   provide this functionality.
>
> Reliable delivery: All of the data needed for a conversation--a set of
>   related communications between two or more services--is persisted in
>   SQL Server. Service Broker supports clustering and database mirroring.
>   A conversation may be maintained through system restarts, server
>   failover, network outages, and so on without failing or losing data.
>
> Improved scalability: Service Broker routing delivers messages based
>   on the name of the service, rather than on the network address of the
>   computer where the service runs. This allows you to install an
>   application on multiple computers without changing application code.
>
> Ability to leverage existing knowledge: Service Broker uses
>   Transact-SQL to create objects. Applications that use Service Broker
>   are most often implemented in Transact-SQL or Microsoft .NET
>   Framework-compatible languages. You do not have to learn a new
>   language to create Service Broker applications.
>
> For further detail check this link
>   http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

1. Service brokers are useful when we want do asynchronous processing in the database. which will improve the performance.
2. When we need inter database communication.

you can find sample code for creating and sending the messages using service broker [here](http://mysoftwareexperience.blogspot.in/2016/02/creating-service-broker-sample-scripts.html).